# Get value returned on Observable <any> in Angular Typescript (Firebase)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

So, I have the following code to retrieve the data from my Firebase User List:

```
currentUserRef: AngularFireList<any>
currentUser: Observable<any>;

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

this.currentUserRef = this.af.list('usuarios', ref =>
ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo(user.email));
this.currentUser = this.currentUserRef.valueChanges();
this.currentUser.subscribe(res => console.log(res[0].condominio));
```

Inside the data retrieved I have two properties: condominio, and email.

On console.log(res[0].condominio) I have the data outputed to console, but I need to save it to a variable, for example:

```
userCond: string;
```

Then I have to get the property 'condominio' from res and set it to 'userCond', but if I try to do this it doesn't work:

```
this.currentUser.subscribe((res) => { this.userCond = res[0].condominio });
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
"firebase": "^5.3.1",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
```

EDIT:

```
    export class HomePage {

    currentUserRef: AngularFireList<any>
    currentUser: Observable<any>;

    moradorRef: AngularFireList<any>
    morador: Observable<any>;

   userCond: string;

   constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    public userService: UserService,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public af: AngularFireDatabase
   ) {

   }

   ionViewCanEnter(): Promise<boolean> {
     return this.authService.authenticated;
   }

   ionViewDidLoad(){
    debugger;
    //TRAZ AS MESMAS INFORMAÇÕES
    //this.userService.getCurrentUser();
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    //const _this = this;

    this.currentUserRef = this.af.list('usuarios', ref =>
    ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo(user.email));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserRef.valueChanges();
    //this.currentUser.subscribe(res => 
    console.log(res[0].condominio));
    this.currentUser.subscribe(res => {
      debugger;
      this.userCond = res[0].condominio;
    });

    console.log(this.userCond);
```

Comment: I don't know Firebase, but what doesn't work? Are you trying to retrieve the value of `userCond` in your HTML? Is `console.log(this.userCond)` not printing the desired output under subscription.. Did you try safe navigation in you HTML ?? https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator

Comment: No, first of all I get the email from the user currently logged in, then I have to go to my firebase list of users search for that email, and once found get the 'condominio' property from that item. I'm not trying to use it in my HTML, I just have to get this property from firebase list.

Comment: Right, so you have that in your subscription.. as you say, `console.log()` prints correctly... then you assign it to a variable and then you want to what? Where do you want to use that variable? In another method? If so, when are you calling that other method?

Comment: It appears that you are using `angularfire2` - can you please share/edit your question with version of the `angularfire2` or `@angular/fire` you are using, along with a little more detailed code listing?

Comment: I have to retrieve as a string the value of property 'condominio', so I can use it to loop another list (which has the name of 'condominio').

Comment: @Neelavar done!

Comment: I believe the problem is you are using the `userCond` outside subscribtion.. for example `console.log(this.userCond)` is outside ... Its not that you can't use it outside subscription, but you have to wait for the susbscription to finish... Subscrition is asynchronous... your `console.log()` will run before yoor subscription finishes...

Comment: @AshishRanjan ohh, I see! So what I've to do to wait til my subscription is finished? Cuz I need this value outside the subscribe().

Comment: Actually, there is nothing wrong with your code of accessing data from the Firebase. Where & How do you wish to use the variable `userCond`? As Ashish mentioned, it could be timing issue as the subscription is async operation.

Comment: I recommend to define the `userCond` as an `Observable<string>` and `map` to get the observable value into it, so that you don't have to subscribe. In the template code, you can use the `async` pipe to get the value during runtime.

Comment: @Neelavar I have to do this after the subscrible ends: let path = userCond + '/moradores' to set the moradorRef.

Comment: Please share your template code as well, it'll be easy to complete the answer then.

Comment: @Neelavar I'll not use it on my template for now, I just have to recover the data and the upcoming I know what to do.

Comment: In that case, you get the `userCond` value only on Subscription asynchronously. So, if you are checking the `userCond` value, you may have to do it under the subscription only. Another option is to define the `userCond` as a `BehaviorSubject` and call `next` with the value inside the subscription. Then you can observe the `userCond` (since it is a Subject) and get the updates asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.currentUser.subscribe(res => {
    this.userCond = res[0].condominio; // 'this' here refers to the observable, not the class instance
  });
```

To handle this, do:

```
  const _this = this;
  this.currentUser.subscribe(res => {
    _this.userCond = res[0].condominio;
  });
```

Comment: By doing that I'm getting undefined on _this.userCond.

Comment: `userCond` should be declared in the class as a variable, along with `currentUser` and `currentUserRef`

Comment: Yeah, I have the following: export class HomePage { currentUserRef: AngularFireList<any>, currentUser: Observable<any> and userCond: any; }, and the const _this = this; I've declared on ionViewDidLoad, that is where I try to retrieve the values. Is that right?

Comment: hmm, i suggest placing breakpoints in your code, then try to print the values on the browser console -- here's a ref if that's yet a foreign method of debugging for you https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints

are you doing `console.log` on `ionViewDidLoad` ? not a good idea. `ionViewDidLoad`'s concern is the template (view) only, not the data that comes from the server

Comment: @jmdavalos: There is no problem with `this` reference.. ES6's arrow operation with preserve the calling context

Comment: This is just a try, a test to recover the values from firebase. Then I'll put the logic into a method on the provider/service, don't worry. Moving on, the '_this' I get based on what you told me to do contains the parameters passed on the constructor, and not my variables declared on the class. Is that right? That's why I'm getting undefined since userCond is not on the _this context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you need to wait for the Subscription to finish before using the class variable `userCond`. Subscriptions are not Synchronous, just call method which you want to use from under the Subscription.

```
this.currentUser.subscribe(res => {
  this.userCond = res[0].condominio;
  this.loopOverAnotherList();
});

loopOverAnotherList() {
   // you can use this.userCond here
}
```

Comment: @Neelavar: It will guarantee If I am calling this only from under my subscription... The thing is, the method will not make the code inside Subscription to clutter..

Answer (score 0):

Define the `userCond` as an Observable.

```
userCond: Observable<string>;
```

Later, map the `condominio` property value into `userCond`, while querying the firestore.

```
this.currentUserRef = this.af.list('usuarios', ref =>
                              ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo(user.email));
this.userCond = this.currentUserRef.valueChanges()
                                       .pipe(map(res => res[0].condominio));
```

Now the `userCond` can be subscribed to get the value, whenever required.